# Storing Comments with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Friends I wrote the following code to insert comments (like Facebook) in MySQL but i didn't succeeded. please help me.

This is the html page

```
    <html>
<head><title>ABC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="try1.php">
    <input type="text" name="like">
    <input type="submit" name="Comment" value="dislike">    
</form>
</body>
```

Now here is the php code

```
    <html>
<head><title> </title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <?

//connecting to database

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(!$conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
  mysql_select_db("try", $conn);
    $a= array('comments' =>'$_GET["like"]');

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO try1 (Comments) VALUES ('$a')",$conn);
  echo "Record Inserted in table";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
```

MySQL is just showing 'Array'. it Just stores 'Array' in the MySQL Field
Please help me!

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: values are inserting to table???

Comment: now change your password

Comment: @ Fasil kk yes but the word 'array' is just inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$a= array('comments' =>'$_GET["like"]');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO try1 (count) VALUES ('$a')",$conn);
```

with this:

```
$a= array('comments' =>$_GET["like"]);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO try1 (count) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($a['comments'])."')",$conn);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Your Issue

You are trying to insert an array into the query!

You need to extract the value from the array. You can either loop through the array (this will allow for multiple values), or you can extract the individual value.

The following example loops through your array and builds the query:

```
foreach($array as $column => $value){
    // Append the columns string with the column name
    $columns .= "`$column`,";
    // Escape and append the values string
    $values .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."',";
}

// Remove the trailing commas
rtrim($columns, ",");
rtrim($values, ",");

$SQL = "INSERT INTO try1 ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

mysql_query($SQL,$conn);
```

Alternatively, you can just extract and escape the array value like so

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO try1 (count) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($a['comments'])."')",$conn);
```

### Some Advice

Please refrain from using `mysql_*` functions they are now deprecated! See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php). You should use either PDO or Mysqli.

See these references:

1. [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
2. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @Ashish See my edit. You need to be sure to escape your data! Furthermore, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions!

Comment: @ Ben Do you think i can learn this much programming language at this age of 15 years.

Comment: @Ashish I did! Everything I know is self taught from the age of 9. Sites like SO really help as it is what they are here for... My answer may seem complicated but if you break it down, it is quite simple, and you will learn a lot :-). If you have any further questions please feel free to email me. My address is in my profile :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this:

```
 $a= array('comments' =>'$_GET["like"]');

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO try1 (Comments) VALUES ('$a')",$conn);
```

as `$a` is not a String, so when you include it in the string argument it is simply outputted as "Array" hence why you see array in the database.

This would work

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO try1 (Comments) VALUES ('{$a['comments']}')",$conn);
```

However, Id strongly suggest listening to advice in the comments of the question. Although useful for a learnign exercise, you may want to look into using a php web framework like codeigniter or cakephp